# Is it possible to render two adjacent VueJS components?

Tags: vue.js

I have created two custom VueJS components and I would like to place them adjacent to one another like so:

```
<div id="app">
      <x-component />   
      <y-component />
</div>

...
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'x-component': { template: '<div>component x</div>' },
        'y-component': { template: '<div>component y</div>' }
    }
});
```

When I do this, only the first component is rendered. Is this a bug in VueJS or am I doing something wrong? It seems like this should be possible.

When I change it as follows, it works:

```
<div id="app">
      <div>
        <x-component />   
      </div>
      <div>
        <y-component />
      </div>
</div>
```

Reproductions below:

Not working:
https://jsfiddle.net/mquqonuq/1/

Working:
https://jsfiddle.net/mquqonuq/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't remember right now if it's an html spec issue but custom web elements need to be a two tag closed system, not a self closed single element.

Try:

```
<div id="app">
    <x-component></x-component>
    <y-component></y-component>
</div>
```

Which works.

EDIT:
if you look at google's [web components primer](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) it lists

```
3. Custom elements cannot be self-closing because HTML only allows a few elements to be self-closing. Always write a closing tag (<app-drawer></app-drawer>).
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I had read that before, but I had somehow convinced myself that it was an issue with the components interacting with each other since VueJS did render the first component as a self-closing single element.

Comment: HTML is remarkably forgiving that way, what I think was happening was that it was Vuejs was taking your `<y-component />` as a content slot value and since `<x-component>` didn't have a `<slot></slot>` inside it nothing was rendered.

Comment: Which Seems to be the case @PageBrooks [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mquqonuq/3/)